# list picker asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list picker asp.net one is assigned techs and unassigned techs my problem I need to remove the duplicate's name form  unassigned I need a way to delete mike from list box b

```
list box A
Mike 

list box B
Mike 
Adam 
TOm
```

Comment: Can you show some code you've already attempted?

Answer (score 0):

You can try .ExceptWith method